# Rails 3.2.3 and ajax - update current page index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

There is a partial view that loads photos by clicking a link. A method test_method requires page_id to load them. After it loaded them page_id must be incremented and link "More photos" as well.

**#home/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "More photos", {:controller => "home", :action => "test_method", :page=>@current_page }, :remote => true,:id => 'lnk_more' %>
<input type=hidden value="<%=@current_page%>"  id='current_page' />
```

**controller**

```
def test_method
    @current_page  = params[:page]
    @paged_photos = get_photos( :page=>@current_pag )
    @current_page +=1
    respond_to() do |format|
      format.js
end
```

**#home/test_method.js.erb**

```
$("#current_page").val(<%= @current_page%>);
```

However it doesn't work because I do something wrong. What am doing wrong and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? There is a typo in your controller code -
replace

```
@paged_photos = get_photos( :page=>@current_pag )
```

with

```
@paged_photos = get_photos( :page=>@current_page )
```

and close respond_to with an end